# Mesibo auto delete all messages after a period of time

Tags: mesibo

Is there a way/line of code that you can insert in Android Studio project to auto delete all messages in the android app that are older than let's say 7 days?

I would like to have all messages canceled/deleted after 7 days of when they where seen/read.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Mesibo.deleteMessagesOlderThan()` API and pass the number of seconds to delete messages older than. To delete messages older than 7 days (604800 seconds), use:

```
Mesibo.deleteMessagesOlderThan(604800);
```

You would want to call this when the app loads or periodically in a background service, for example,

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    
    // Delete messages older than 7 days
    Mesibo.deleteMessagesOlderThan(604800); 
  }

}
```

This will automatically clean up older messages without any additional coding.

For older mesibo API versions, you can use `Mesibo.deleteMessages(ts)` instead and pass the timestamp from 7 days ago.

Refer to the https://docs.mesibo.com/api/messaging/deleting-and-recalling-messages/

You may also use disappearing messages if desired

https://docs.mesibo.com/api/messaging/disappearing-messages/